# Exiftool time adjust only for photos taken with camera

Tags: metadata, exiftool, apple

This is a tricky one.

I take pictures and videos with both an iPhone and a Sony camera and import them into the Photos.app in the Mac. 
I do a little cleanup, delete unwanted photos and then export the original JPG files to a folder (no conversion). Pictures are automatically renamed and sorted into subfolders using Hazel and a Exiftool script.

The pictures for both devices register the correct GMT offset for date and time and Exiftool renames then perfectly.

Videos are a different story. 
The iPhone register the correct GMT offset and videos are correctly renamed.
The Sony camera theoretically does it right too and when I import into the Photos.app the time is correct (in my case GMT -3) when I look at the info pane.
The Problem: When I export the original videos the metadata does not recognize the GMT offset, so the time of the videos are always 3 hours more than it should. It resets to GMT +0.

When I export the videos I don’t know which device took it unless I look at the metadata.

Is the a script to identify just the videos taken with the Sony Camera and correct the GMT offset?

Comment: Can you post your exiftool commands, the make and model of the Sony camera, and if possible, link to a short video from the camera?  The fix might just be as simple as a check for the camera model and adding `-api quicktimeutc` to the command.

Comment: Here are the specs and script:

Camera model: Sony RX100 Mark I (1st gen)
Exiftool command for movies: exiftool -d  %Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S  '-filename<${CreationDate;}.%e' "$1"

Exiftool info of a movie taken with the camera, after the export from Photos.app. Look for “Creation Date” in the end of the log. The video was taken 18:12:05 but the info states 21:12:05.
exiftool -a /Volumes/BUFFALO3/Sync/2016-12-27_211205.mov 

Creation Date                   : 2016:12:27 21:12:05

Comment: I've looked around and I can't find an unaltered sample video in order figure out the proper tag to differentiate between Sony RX 100 videos and other videos.  If you can figure out a tag that's unique to the Sony videos, you can try this command for videos:  `exiftool -if '$TAG eq "VALUE"' -api quicktimeutc -execute -if '$TAG ne "VALUE"' -common_args -ext mp4 -ext mov -d %Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S '-filename<${CreationDate;}.%e' `.  You would have to replaces `TAG` with the name of the tag that is unique to Sony videos and `VALUE` with the value of that tag.

Comment: I found this unique tag for the Sony camera videos.
Description                     : AVCHD: /Volumes/RPBG_SD32/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV
I tried your script like this: 
exiftool -if '$Description eq "AVCHD: /Volumes/RPBG_SD32/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV"' -api quicktimeutc -execute -if '$Description ne "AVCHD: /Volumes/RPBG_SD32/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV"' -common_args -ext mp4 -ext mov -d %Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S '-filename<${CreationDate;}.%e' “$1”
The script returns an error but renames the file with the same GMT +0, no correction.

Comment: Based on your idea, I tried another script using the globaltimeshift option and it worked OK.
exiftool -if '$Description eq "AVCHD: /Volumes/RPBG_SD32/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV"' -globalTimeShift "-0:0:0 3:0:0" -d  %Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S  '-filename<${CreationDate;}.%e' "$1"
Thanks StarGeek.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  GlobalTimeShift was the other option I was trying to think of, but couldn't remember it.  Since it defaults to reading the input number as hours unless otherwise formatted, you should be able to just use `-GlobalTimeShift -3`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recognized bug in LR, and it is fixed in the newest version (Lightroom CC 2015.10/Lightroom 6.10).

See the LR changelog under https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/iphone_video_capture_time_is_shifted_upon_import_to_lightroom